# reading data from binary value in php?

Tags: php

I get the below binary value in php by collecting the value from a DB.

```
0xF4010800000000960106000000002f03040000000063030700000000...
```

The problem is i don't know how to read it in sections.

For example, the first part `F401` should be returned as a smallint (2 bytes) `500` and then just after that `08000000` should be returned as an int (4 bytes unsigned) and return as `8`, how is this done in PHP?

EDIT:

I have tried `hexdec(substr($value, 0, 4))` to try and get the value 500. bit on the first 4 bytes but this dosen't work, i don't know what else to try.

Comment: Wel [what have you tried so far](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: `$hex = bin2ex($binary);` and `$dec = hex2dec($dec);`

Answer (score 1):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php

Note: Your data is packed in little-endian.

```
$bin = hex2bin('F4010800000000960106000000002f03040000000063030700000000');
var_dump(unpack('vone/itwo/h*remain', $bin));
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  ["one"]=>
  int(500)
  ["two"]=>
  int(8)
  ["remain"]=>
  string(44) "0069106000000000f230400000000036307000000000"
}
```